# spring data jpa selecting values considering the date and time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity which is

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "REFRESH_TOKENS")
public class JwtRefreshToken {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TOKEN")
    private String token;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Tbluser user;

    @Column(name = "EXPIRATIONDATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime expirationDateTime;

    public JwtRefreshToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

}
```

and the the corresponding repository is

```
    JwtRefreshToken findByTokenAndAndExpirationDateTimeBefore( String token, @Param("expirationDateTime")  LocalDateTime localDateTime);
```

The interesting thing here is the query always returns value even though the time has exceeded.

for example the value stored in database is 2019-04-21 22:33:08

and my current date time is 2019-04-21T23:02:43.971
but yet the above `findByTokenAndAndExpirationDateTimeBefore`  returns value.

i want to compare the time as well.

Comment: try with `LessThan` like `findByTokenAndAndExpirationDateTimeLessThan`

Comment: it does not work

Comment: Then you have to write custom query

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug output to see parameterized query and its parameters, add to your application properties

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Probably, you will get some clues if query does not use `@Param("expirationDateTime")  LocalDateTime localDateTime` at all or there is timezone issue or everything is fine and you just misinterpret results ;)